# out.println says out cannot be resolved

Tags: java, servlets

When I write `out.println()`, eclipse complains that out cannot be resolved.

I have imported `java.io.*` and other servlet packages.

Comment: Do you have more than 1 class named "System" ?

Comment: Or alternatively use `System.out.println()` directly, since the `java.lang` package is imported implicitly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just a shot in the dark, I think this is the `out` you are looking for:

```
public class OutServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("foo");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
```

Answer (score 4):

You should write `System.out.println();` inside a function.

If you write it directly into the class then it might show the error that you are having right now.

Answer (score 2):

Import it using a `static` import:

```
    import static java.lang.System.out;
```

However, I'd recommend that you don't do this.

- Using the full name makes references to `System.out` stand out, and makes them easier to "grep" for ... if you need to nuke traceprints.
- If you need to write a lot of stuff to the console, you should make `out` a variable or a method parameter.  This will help to make your code more reusable; e.g. so that it can write to somewhere other than `System.out`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. I found out I didn't have main method( public static void main(string[]args) and that is why it was giving me this error. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If your are looking to put some debug outputs, you can do this:

```
System.out.println("foo");
```

If your are looking for adding the output to HTML not printing on debug console you can do as follow:
First you should add the 'servlet-api.jar' to your project. Then simply you can use this if you want to add your output to HTML:

```
response.getWriter().println("foo");
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

Can you please check whether you are having any class name as "System" ?
This could be one reason.
Like in the code below if I use class name as System it would end up with the same Error like yours.

> Cannot use Identifier 'System' as Class name;

```
public class System {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int A[] = { 3, 9, 7, 8, 12, 6, 15, 5, 4, 10 };

    for (int x : A) {
        System.out.print(x + ", ");

    }
    System.out.println("\n*******************");
    int t = A[A.length - 1];

    System.out.println(t);

}

}
```

Comment: The answer is far away from topic. Even so you should try to propose something which will solve the issue, not another way of reproduce. Note also, is a very old question and most likely the OP issues is long solved (even if not, does OP still have the original code ? and environment in order to reproduce ? is OP still online?). Regarding off-topic, kindly look at tags and do some research regarding servlets. Main reason for down-voting is off-topic.