# IntelliJ System.out.println() - Cannot resolve method println(java.lang.String)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, println

I am using IntelliJ IDEA, learning Java. All went well until yesterday, when the mentioned error occurred.

I didn't make any changes. I was looking for the solution the following ways:

1. reboot the pc
2. restart IntelliJ.
3. delete the project directory and use another one (both on desktop)

nothing helps. buy running simple hello world method. It keeps showing this error:

[image: screenshot]

Is there someone able to help me?

Comment: Add: I am not using any addon, or "Marven". it simply stops to work. And normally no import should be needed for println method. This error corrupted all my previous learning projects. So it doesn't seems to be local or connect to any single class.

Comment: I am having the same problem... As "workaround" I am using `java.lang.System.out.println()`

Comment: @D.Kastier ur "workaround" also didn't work for me.

Comment: @Prabesh Bhattarai in my case, I found out latter that was an user class also named `System`, there fore caused conflict with the java's `System` class.

Answer (score 97):

ok, is solved.

file -> invalidated caches / Restart

Comment: Thanks. This also helped me with Intellij Idea 2021.1

Comment: worked for me as well, first time user of this IDE

Answer (score 22):

One reason for this to happen is if you have print statement somewhere on the body of the class, and not inside a method.

Here is an example:

[image]

But if the print is inside a method, it should work fine.

Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: The OP does not have this problem.

Answer (score 11):

I think if you have tried the method above, maybe you can consider where you use `System.out.println()` because this method should only used in `main(String args[]){}`,the latest version of the Idea is OK. I wish what said can help you.

Comment: That's not true. You can use it in any method you like, as long as it is not directly on class level.

Answer (score 6):

case 1: if all sdk setup is complete and perfect
then
file -> invalidated caches / Restart
this could work

case 2 : if something missing in sdk setup of intelij
then goto

1. file->project structure->libraries
2. click on + button
3. add location of lib folder of tomcat directory
   `C:\xampp\tomcat\lib`
   [image: to add lib directory to tomcat]

Answer (score 5):

If you have orcale sdk configured as your project sdk there is no way `System.out.println` can't be found - besides you are using another `System.out`.

So my guess is that you don't have a proper project sdk configured.

Goto to Project Settings or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, go to `Project Settings -> Project` and check if your sdk is setup correctly.

Answer (score 3):

In my case my project was set up to Java 6th and I had installed jre1.8.0_131 which I assume was causing the problem. After changing Java to level 8 problem have been solved.

Press Ctrl+Alt+Shift+s or go to File -> Project Structure -> Project, and set Project Language Level to yours.

Answer (score 1):

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
```

Or do you possibly have more than one class named System?

Or possibly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11417686/out-println-says-out-cannot-be-resolved) link could be of use to you.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that your SDK in the setting of INTELIJI is set up [have a look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCVP5.png)

I had that problem because I pulled the repository from work where we have java 8, but on my private computer, I have 17..

Answer (score 0):

This happens with me when i was try to add the print statement without outside the main method
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTwjr.png)
then I create the main method error get resolve
[error resolve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssQiF.png)

Comment: This appears to be a different issue from OP's, even though the error message is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Goto to Project Settings or press Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S, go to Project Settings -> Project and check if your sdk is setup correctly.
OR
-> rename your project folder
for example ~/folder/folder2
To
~/folder

Answer (score 0):

### The Problem I faced

- I had the same problem when I was trying to run my Java file inside my Eclipse IDE.
- I used the following steps to find out the error and resolve them.

#### Errors I faced

- `Cannot resolve method println(java.lang.String)`
- `Cannot resolve method ArrayList`
- And every method of ArrayList and Collections Framework threw an error.

#### Solution

1. From the menu bar of IntelliJ IDE, Click **File**
2. Then click on Invalidated Caches... (As shown in the screenshot)
   [image: IntelliJ - Cannot resolve method println Error Step 1]
3. Then Click **Invalidate and Restart** button. (As shown in the screenshot)

[image: IntelliJ - Cannot resolve method println Error Step 2]

- After carefully checking out the answers from other users, I have created a detailed answer with screenshots for the community.
- Shoutout to the user [@user6479494](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6479494/user6479494) who posted a similar solution, that worked for me, using which I was able to resolve the error I faced.

I hope this was helpful!